# Best approach to dynamic menu system

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

Morning!

I'm currently writing a new bit of software which has a lot of menu items. At the moment I have the menu structure defined in embedded XML, along with permissions for each item and the menu draws correctly.

I'm after some suggestions on the best approach for linking each menu item to a method which will run when it's selected.  Just now, each menu item has a unique ID, so I thought I'd have all of the menu items call one method which will then call a specific method for that menu item but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Also, what is the best way to call a method using the method name stored in a string. I have methods called "MenuOption_xxx", where xxx is the ID - but I need to call that method when the menu item is selected.

Any pointers or better suggestions are appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: why do you store method names as strings. Why just not store delegates in your menuItem class?

Comment: Good question - I'm not hot with delegates, so I'm fishing for ideas on how best to tackle the problem. Do you have an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Reflection`, for example calling an object method by name:

```
Type yourType= yourObject.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("MenuOption_xxx"); 
theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
```

You can set your menus `Tag` property as identifier:

```
menuItem1.Tag = "X"; // name or id of this menuitem
menuItem2.Tag = "XX";
menuItem3.Tag = "XXX";
```

then set `Click` event:

```
menuItem1.Click += MenuItem_Click;
menuItem2.Click += MenuItem_Click;
menuItem3.Click += MenuItem_Click;
```

on the `Click` event:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var id = (String) ((MenuItem))sender.Tag;

    // use reflection:
    Type yourType= yourObject.GetType();
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(String.Format("MenuOption_{0}", id)); 
    theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
}

public void MenuOption_X
{
 ...
}
public void MenuOption_XX
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used a modified version of this successfully and it does the trick nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a solution with delegates would look like this:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public delegate ActionResult MenuAction(ActionParams params);
}
```

You should declare ActionResult and ActionParams classes and include all the members you need in them. You can even make them abstract and inherit from them for each individual case.

Then, from code, calling the MenuAction would look like this:

```
var closeWindow = new MenuItem{.......}; //initialize your variable or call a constructor

var result = closeWindow.MenuAction(params); //pass some params
```